# Spring MVC Controller opens wrong .jsp file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

my project structure looks like below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The issue is**  when I return in HomeController .jsp file named *"home"* and run this project on Tomcat server I receive website but not from *home.jsp*, but *index.jsp* **(1 screenshot)**.

My question is is there any file where starting .jsp file is defined as a launcher ? If not so why  *index.jsp* always launches while Controller Class returns a different file  ?

Comment: Let's post code snippet, not take screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
I have created a new project (Maven project + Web archetype) and works fine. I assume that a problem was with location of web folder. Now I have it inside *src* folder unlike in previous structure.